# Oracle "not a GROUP BY expression error"

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I have the following SQL expression:

```
SELECT PROFESSOR_NAME, SUBJECT_NAME, NUMBER_OF_CREDITS, PERCENT,
  (SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID)
    FROM SUBJSTUD
    WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS,
  0.4*NUMBER_OF_CREDITS*PERCENT*(
    SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID)
    FROM SUBJSTUD
    WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID)*18/120) AS PAYMENT_PER_SUBJECT,
  SUM(0.4*NUMBER_OF_CREDITS*PERCENT*(
    SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID) 
    FROM SUBJSTUD
    WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID)*18/120) AS PAYMENT_PER_PROFESSOR
FROM SUBJECT, PROFESSOR, TEACHES
WHERE PROFESSOR.PROFESSOR_ID = TEACHES.PROFESSORID 
AND SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID = TEACHES.SUBJECTID
AND POCETOK_UCEBNA = :UCEBNA_GODINA
AND SEMESTAR = :SEMESTAR
AND PROFESsOR.STUDISKAPROGRAMA = :STUDISKAPROGRAMA
GROUP BY PROFESSOR_NAME, SUBJECT_NAME, NUMBER_OF_CREDITS, PERCENT
```

The parameters are taken from list boxes. Without the SUM, it works fine, but I need that last calculation to generate a report that will sum all the payments per subject for each professor. The problem is probably in the sub-expression (`SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID) FROM SUBJSTUD WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID`), but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Why are you using three sub-expressions at all, rather than joining to `SUBJSTUD`? You might want to consider using `JOIN` syntax as well, though that isn't relevant to your problem. Your `NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS` and `PAYMENT_PER_SUBJECT` aren't being aggregated and aren't in the `GROUP BY`, which is what it's complaining about.

Comment: The problem here is that your (SELECT COUNT...) expression is neither the aggregate, nor something that you group by.  How Oracle is supposed to know which row to use?

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to wrap `PAYMENT_PER_SUBJECT` into `SUM`()?

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing openning bracket in your query, try:

```
SELECT PROFESSOR_NAME, SUBJECT_NAME, NUMBER_OF_CREDITS, PERCENT,
  (SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID)
    FROM SUBJSTUD
    WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS,
  (0.4*NUMBER_OF_CREDITS*PERCENT*(
    SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID)
    FROM SUBJSTUD
    WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID)*18/120) AS PAYMENT_PER_SUBJECT,
  SUM(0.4*NUMBER_OF_CREDITS*PERCENT*(
    SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID) 
    FROM SUBJSTUD
    WHERE SUBJSTUD.SUBJECTID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID)*18/120) AS PAYMENT_PER_PROFESSOR
FROM SUBJECT, PROFESSOR, TEACHES
WHERE PROFESSOR.PROFESSOR_ID = TEACHES.PROFESSORID 
AND SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID = TEACHES.SUBJECTID
AND POCETOK_UCEBNA = :UCEBNA_GODINA
AND SEMESTAR = :SEMESTAR
AND PROFESsOR.STUDISKAPROGRAMA = :STUDISKAPROGRAMA
GROUP BY PROFESSOR_NAME, SUBJECT_NAME, NUMBER_OF_CREDITS, PERCENT;
```

Comment: You can't use a column alias in a `group by` in the same level, only in an `order by`. You could use a subquery for the whole thing, but I'm not sure it would be needed if it was joined properly.

Comment: Right, thank you, corrected the query. It won't work anyways but he did missed the bracket.. ;)

Comment: You can, but I'd rather use a nested query to avoid the duplication. I'm just not convinced it'll end up with the result the OP is actually looking for, which isn't very clear...

Comment: How do I aggregate the NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS and PAYMENT_PER_SUBJECT so that I could use them? I don't have a lot of experience in this.

Comment: At the end I need to sum all the PAYMENT_PER_SUBJECT for each PROFESSOR_NAME.